# Find if a number is divisible by another number using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

How would I check if a number is divisible by another using recursion in python?

This is my code so far, but I would like to make it recursive.

```
def is_divisable(num, div):
    if num % div == 0:
        return True
    else:
        False
```

Comment: to check the divisibility of one number from another, why do you need recursion? `a % b` does the trick, right ?

Comment: yeah just curious on how the recursion would work

Comment: Its simply not a recursive problem, don't over think it.

Comment: Btw there is a typo, it should be "divisible" not "divisable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For educational purposes, you could keep subtracting until you reach 0 or below:

```
def is_divisible(num, div):
    while(num > 0):
        num -= div
    return num == 0
```

Using this logic you can make it recursive (Thanks to Anonymous for pointing out the above version is not recursive):

```
def is_divisible(num, div):
    if (num == 0):
        return True
    elif (num < 0):
        return False
    return is_divisible(num-div, div)
```

However, the correct way would be:

```
def is_divisible(num, div):
    return num % div == 0
```

Comment: this logic could be used to write recursive function, but this is not recursive function

Comment: Btw there is a typo, it should be "divisible" not "divisable"

Comment: Importantly, this approach would be less efficient than the more obvious use of modulus, so I'm not sure why you'd explicitly want to do this (other than as a learning exercise). Though what would it really achieve in terms of teaching, given that this problem isn't really meant to be solved this way? I imagine it would just lead to confusion more than anything. If the point is to teach loops & recursion, there are plenty of more relevant & interesting examples than divisibility.

Comment: I guess it could help beginners understand recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_divisable(num,div):
    if num<div:
        return num %div==0
    else:
        return is_divisable(num-div,div)
```